# Why was the final shootout scene shot in a very dark violet tint?

Tags: analysis, lighting, running-scared

In *Running Scared (2005)*, There is a final shootout scene at an Ice Hockey rink, but this scene looks very violet/blue.

[image]

Why final shootout scene shot in very dark tint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Essentially, because that's what the director, Wayne Kramer wanted.

From an interview...

> It was very expensive to light and the producers were trying to talk me out of it — which I’m glad didn’t happen. I was doing some ice hockey research on the internet and came across this Jet Ice black light paint and immediately thought that would be **amazing to capture on film**.
>
> I don’t think we quite executed it the way I had in mind — due to technical difficulties and lack of time — but I envisioned more bullet impacts in the ice with the ice shattering into different colors and exploding through the air. I think we got just a hint of that; we were more successful with the fluorescent pucks and the DayGlo jerseys.
>
> **I also wanted the scene to be a significant set piece — this is where it all goes down, so to speak, and I wanted the backdrop to be memorable.**
>
> <sup>[Medium.com](https://medium.com/applaudience/running-scared-a-conversation-with-wayne-kramer-a23cbb90864)</sup>